# How to check if a text is a number

Tags: c

So I wanted to check if a text is a number (0..9) using `isdigit` but it seems that it doesn't work, I've tried several times but...

I want to verify if the text is like this `06...`

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef enum {
    false,
    true
} boolean;

int main()
{
    boolean trouv = true;
    int i = 0;
    signed char a[20];
    scanf("%s", a);
    signed char op[20];
    op[0] = a[0];
    op[1] = a[1];
    if (strcmp(op, "06") == 0)
        printf("oui");
    else
        printf("non");

    while (trouv == true) {
        if (isdigit(a[i]) != 0) {
            trouv = false;
        } else
            i++;
    }
       
    if (trouv == true)
        printf("yeddddd");
    else
        printf("nnnnn");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indention and code formatting, this isn't readable.

Comment: How do you define "a number"? Is `0xDEADBEEF` a number for you? How about `99999999999999999999` (this value exceeds `2**64`)? How about `090`? (This begins with `0`, but invalid as octal)

Comment: 'op' is not null-terminated, but you use 'strcmp' on it

Comment: @MikeCat a decimal number

Comment: @SarahSARAH: Containing numerical digits only (no `+` or `-` sign, no decimal point, no thousands separators - e.g. not `-1,234.56`)?

Comment: You never increment `i`

Comment: Why don't you use "%d" instead of "%s"? Seems like a round-a-bout way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

As @lulle mentioned, `op` is a character array, not a string. So it is not null-terminated. If you want to check specifically for `06`, you can check with a hard-coded string literal `"06"`. For checking if the string only contains digits, you have to loop through its characters and check each character.

```
int main ()
{
    int i=0;
    signed char a[20];
    boolean trouve;
    scanf("%s",a);
    
    //Check if 06
    if (strcmp("06", a) == 0) 
    {
        printf("\nOui");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nNon");
    }
    
    //Check if number:
    for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(a[i]))
        {
            printf("\nText is not a number");
            trouve = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (a[i] == '\0')
    {
        printf("\nText is a number");
        trouve = true;
    }
}
```

It's better to wrap them in two functions:

```
boolean is_06(char* str)
{
    return strcmp("06", str) ? false : true; 
}
```

```
boolean is_string_digit(char* str)
{
    for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(a[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In `main()`:

```
int main ()
{
    int i=0;
    signed char a[20];
    scanf("%s",a);

    if (is_06(a))
    {
        printf("Oui");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Non");
    }

    
    if (is_string_digit(a))
    {
        printf("Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: @SarahSARAH I've updated my answer, now it checks if a string is only composed of digits or not. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First beware char array's they arent fully strings persay as they aren't null terminated, so using strcmp should be causing some issues, second you dont need booleans in C, just use a unsigned char: 0 means false, everything else means 1(you can do if(var) and if its more than 1 it will suceed the condition

also isdigit only works for single characters, so imagine you have an input and its "a05" it would return 0,1,1 not 0,1 (you have to input everything once at a time)
Also saying if ( isdigit(a[i])!=0) is redudant just place `if(isdigit(a[i]))`
oh you also never increment i so it keeps checking the a[0] as mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues:

- You never increment `i` in your loop
- You only ever exit the loop, when you read a non-digit character. This means `trouv` will always be false after exiting the loop (at the very latest, when you read the terminating null-character of the string, `isdigit` will return  false).
- `op` is not null-terminated, but you use `strcmp` on it.
- You check if the first two characters are "06", but still continue to check the rest in the loop, even if that is not the case. Im not sure why, so i haven't changed that.

Instead do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
typedef enum {
    false,
    true
} boolean;

int main ()
{
    boolean trouv=true ;
    int i=0;
    signed char a[20];
    scanf("%s", a);
    char op[20];
    op[0]=a[0];
    op[1]=a[1];
    op[2]='\0';
    if (strcmp(op,"06")==0){
        printf("oui");
    }else {
        printf("non");

        while (trouv == true && a[i] != '\0'){
            if ( isdigit(a[i])!=0){
                trouv=false ;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (trouv==true){
        printf("yeddddd");
    }
    else{
        printf("nnnnn");
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot "i++" inside while (trouv == true )
If the first char of 20 length string is not numeric, it loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `scanf("%s", a);` may cause a buffer overflow if the user enters more than 19 characters. Use `scanf("%19s", a);` to avoid this.
- you only copy the first 2 bytes of `a` to `op`: if the string in `a` is longer than 1 character, the null terminator is not set in `op` causing `strcmp(op, "06")` to have undefined behavior.
- the `while` loop tests all bytes in the string including the null terminator, which is not a `digit` hence `trouv` is always `false` after the loop.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[20];
    int i, has_number;

    if (scanf("%19s", a) == 1) {
        has_number = 1;
        for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (!isdigit((unsigned char)a[i]) {
                has_number = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (has_number)
            printf("yes\n");
        else
            printf("no\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can use `strspn()` to test the whole string in a single call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[20];

    if (scanf("%19s", a) == 1) {
        /* check if all characters are in the string "0123456789" */
        int has_number = a[strspn(a, "0123456789")] == '\0';
        if (has_number)
            printf("yes\n");
        else
            printf("no\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly more complicated than is every character within the range of characters needed to form a number. (Is "---" a number?) Depending on what you consider a number, `"-"? [0-9]+`, or maybe `"-"? ([0-9]+ ("." [0-9]*)?) | ([0-9]* "." [0-9]+)`. Fortunately, finding out if it *is* a number is very close to actually parsing it, and this is a very common task; you don't need a regular expression library, `stdlib.h` has [strtol](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strtol.html).

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* strtol */
#include <errno.h> /* errno */
#include <ctype.h> /* isspace */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int a;
    char *endp;
    for(a = 1; a < argc; a++) {
        errno = 0;
        strtol(argv[a], &endp, 10); /* Parse the string as an integer. */
        if(errno) { perror("Nombre"); continue; }
        while(isspace(*endp)) endp++; /* Ignore spaces symmetrically. */
        printf("Entièrement un nombre: %s.\n", *endp == '\0' ? "oui" : "non");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you need a decimal, it is twice as much work.